# UITextView Scroll to Bottom, crop half of character

Tags: ios, uitextview

My app is message app and use `UITextView` to input word so that it could line break. The `UITextView` mechanism is when `UITextView's` height grows enough it will stop and auto-scroll. In the `main.storyboard`, I uncheck the Scrolling Enable. I therefore use `setContentOffset` (like below) to fulfill mechanism.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidChange:) name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGSize contentSizeInTextView = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
    if (contentSizeInTextView.height > _textView.frame.size.height) {
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, contentSizeInTextView.height - _textView.frame.size.height);
    [self.textView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

but when I run the code, it's cropping half of the word, because of the reputation of stackoverflow I can't post the image.

Could you tell  what's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if u r uncheking the default Scroll of textview,Have u added ur textview in scrollview.?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen  That's a nice name! Dose it need to add textView in scrollview?  Is UITextView a subclass of UiscrollView?

Answer (score 1):

There is many controller that you can use, [SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController) is good option.

But there is other as well which you can use, Some of them are...
[1. SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)
[2. whatsapp-ios](https://github.com/rcmcastro/whatsapp-ios)
[3. RDRStickyKeyboardView](https://github.com/datwelk/RDRStickyKeyboardView)
[4. AMMessageComposer](https://github.com/dc7batman/AMMessageComposer)
[5. THSpringyCollectionView](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/THSpringyCollectionView)
[6. Chats](https://github.com/acani/Chats)
[7. ssmessagesviewcontroller](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller)

I will add more control in it in future.

Comment: thanks you give me a convenient  suggest. I will try it.